# How to find the shortest path in a n-ary tree with duplicate node values?

Tags: algorithm, tree, shortest-path

Here is an example:

```
     0
     1 
   2   3 
          2
```

I am looking for the shortest path between 2 and 3, which is equal to 1.

Comment: 1. which "2"? ;) 2. please explain your "path definition" some more detailed. (length or elements = 1?) 3. but instinctually i would "bubble": (why not) try BFS or DFS? :)

Comment: Treating the n-ary tree as an undirectional graph, you could run BFS from each node with value `2` (in your example) and then check its distance from 3 and pick the minimum

Comment: Is [2, 1, 3] a valid path or are you not allowed to go from a child back to a parent

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating sets of pointers to each occurrence of 2 and 3, keeping an integer with each pointer showing the total distance it has moved so far. Make room for a note on each node of the tree saying whether it has been seen by a pointer of each type, and if so, the distance that pointer had accumulated at that time, and the source of the pointer.

Repeatedly move each pointer up the tree one step, incrementing its distance. Look at the notes on the node of the tree it has reached. If this is the same type and the distance is greater than the distance of the pointer, replace the note. If this is the same type and the distance is not greater, two pointers of the same type have collided and you can drop the second pointer. If it is of a different type you have a potential shortest path.

Keep going until every pointer is at the top, or every pointer has travelled at least as far as the shortest path found, because after that any path found must be longer than the shortest path found.

In the worst case we work until the end and we traverse the entire tree, but only once for each type, because a pointer of one type that travels up to a node already passed by another pointer of the same type will see a distance to its node less than its own distance and stop. So the worst case cost is linear in the size of the tree.